# Vue & Vite gives me the minimal Vue folder structure

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vite

I just created my first Vue app with the Vite bundler. I'm used to creating Vue projects with the Webpack bundler & Vue CLI where you can generate the VueX and Vue Router folders and files out of the box. When I create the Vue app with Vite I only get the minimal folder structure.

Is there a way to generate the VueX and the Vue Router Files automatically with Vite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue CLI is a project generation framework which configures build tools and makes it easy to install libraries.
Vite is just a build tool.

You need to set everything up from scratch, or use a template eg: https://github.com/antfu/vitesse